# Description getting generated twice in the output html -JSDOC 4.0.2

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

```
var x= {
/**
*
*
```

This flag set to true,
to work studio in offline mode.

```
@type Boolean */
offline: false
}
```

for the above code jsdoc generating below output in the html. please suggest a workaround to avoid duplicate content

```
(static) offline :Boolean
```

This flag set to true,
to work studio in offline mode.

Type:
Boolean